# CVS override CVS/Root

Tags: linux, ssh, unix, cvs

We have a server that we host web-solutions on, they are updatede on the server with CVS. About 4 people need access to the server and the ability to update the web-solutions through CVS.

When I checkout the web-solution the CVS/Root is set to :ext:USERNAME@ADDRESS:CVS-PATH - Which is fine for as long as I use cvs to update. But if another user (different USERNAME) makes a CVS update, it tries to update it with my username for which the other user doesnt know the password to.

I would like to "force" the cvs-root to be something for each user, but unfortunally the file CVS/Root overrides the enviroment variable CVSROOT.

Is it possible another way to override it, so each user gets to update using thier own login.

Hope someone can help me in the right direction :)

Comment: You are trying to update with different users from the same sandbox?  Err, don't do that.  Create a new sandbox for each user you want to do updates as.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you simply get rid of the USERNAME part and set your CVSROOT to `:ext:ADRESS:CVS-PATH`. You could then change your respective ~/.ssh/config files to include the correct user name for the CVS server.

Alternatively, you could add another user to the system, provide everyone with the password (or better yet with a key) and let that user do the updating.

Answer (score 0):

for each login, you can separately provide, either manually or as part of the login process, a CVSROOT via:

```
export CVSROOT=:ext:USERNAME@ADDRESS:CVS-PATH
```

If this is a permanent thing for each user, then I'd suggest dropping that into the user's /home/user/.bashrc

Just make sure that the separate users are listed in CVS.